# The purpose of the table cataloginventory_stock

Tags: inventory, stock

I see that in the default Magento versions 1.0 to 1.8 (ce) There is a table called `cataloginventory_stock` that contains only one record.

```
stock_id    stock_name
1           Default
```

Related to this, in the `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` model there is this method

```
public function getStockId()
{
    return 1;
}
```

with a comment above it `@todo multi stock`.

I guess someone wanted to implement multi stock functionality and decided not to (like many other "features") but I'm not sure.

So my question is... **Is there any other purpose to this table, does it affect other sections of the code or is just there as a starting point for a new feature?**

Comment: Magento 2 has released. That table is still there and useless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having a look at this table's indexes it does seem to function completely as a standalone addition to the database, **for the time being**.

If you look at the `assignProduct()` method around line 263 of `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php` you'll notice that it references the method itself:

```
 Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock_status')
        ->assignProduct($product, $this->getStockId(), $this->getStockStatus());
```

I'm assuming yes, as you mentioned, for the future platform to be able to handle an inventory system of multi-stock nature.

**Edit:** to expand on my answer, Magento references the `getStockId()` method in a total of 5 files, namely:

- `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Observer.php` on line 204,
- `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Indexer\Stock.php` on line 37,
- `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Resource\Stock\Item.php` on line 57,
- `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item.php` on line 167 and 275, and finally
- `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status.php` on lines 36, 191, 192, 265, 266 and 376

Please note that this is as of Magento 1.7.0.2

Comment: Thanks to the your opinion and the code digging. You just confirmed my suspicions.