# Magento 1: Relationship Between `qty` in Stock Item, and Stock Status Tables

Tags: magento-1, stock, inventory

In Magento 1, Inventory information is stored in a Stock Item object.  Each Stock Item object is associated with a product object.  Magento persists Stock Item objects to the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.

However, each Stock Item object has a related Stock Status object.  Stock Status appears to be an (index|cache|de-normalized) table that stores a product's stock status as in integer constant, and allows you to associate multiple stock items and products with a different `website_id`. Magento persists stock status objects to the `cataloginventory_stock_status`.  The class constants and table schema for this are below.

```
class Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    const STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK       = 0;
    const STATUS_IN_STOCK           = 1;
}

mysql> describe cataloginventory_stock_status;
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id   | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| website_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| stock_id     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| qty          | decimal(12,4)        | NO   |     | 0.0000  |       |
| stock_status | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**However**, for reasons that aren't entirely clear, there is **also** a `qty` column in this table.

What is the relationship between these two `qty` columns?

Which is the source of truth for `qty` and which is the indexed/cached value?  Is the value in `stock_status` simply a cached version of what's in the stock item table?  Or is there a way to configure Magento to manage stock on a website level?  Or is the relationship something other than what I've described?

Comment: Also, is_in_stock field from stock-item table is ignored in product view page.

Comment: Just to make a note - one thing I noticed is that if a product is backorderable the qty can go < 0 in cataloginventory_stock_item, however cataloginventory_stock_status will never go below 0. I don't know why it behaves like this, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks to me like qty in `cataloginventory_stock_item` is the source of truth, and qty in `cataloginventory_stock_status` is the cached/indexed value.  Rebuilding the Stock Status index appears to always copy the value from `cataloginventory_stock_item` into `cataloginventory_stock_status`.  If there are multiple websites, there will also be a record for each product_id/website_id combo in `cataloginventory_stock_status`.  This suggests the possibility of different stock levels per website, but as far as I can tell the qty value is always the same for each one.

I think this may be the beginnings of a multi-stock feature as suggested by Marius in this post:
[The purpose of the table cataloginventory_stock](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/the-purpose-of-the-table-cataloginventory-stock)